# Open Shift Node Js: Server responds error when uploading an image

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, file-upload, openshift

My Open shift node sever crashes when ever I try to upload a photo to the service. The code dealing with this is

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080, process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var url = require("url");
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var fs = require('fs')
//Databse Loading
var Datastore = require('nedb')
, db = new Datastore({ filename: './db/users.json', autoload: true });
postsDB = new Datastore({ filename: './db/posts.json', autoload: true });
followDB = new Datastore({ filename: './db/follow.json', autoload: true });
likeDB = new Datastore({ filename: './db/like.json', autoload: true });
notifDB = new Datastore({ filename: './db/notif.json', autoload: true });

app.use(express.static('frontend'));
app.use(express.static('frontend/uploads'));
app.use('/user', express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use('/uploads', express.static(process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR+'/uploads'));
app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'))
```

The images upload just by using the fs package.

The code that deals with the image placement is as follows

```
  socket.on('Image Post', function(ext, buffer, location, postData) {
  console.log(ext);
  postsDB.insert([postData], function (err, newDocs) {
    if(err){console.log(err)}
    else{
      console.log(newDocs);
      var fileName = process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR + '/frontend/uploads' + "/" + newDocs[0]._id + ext;
      fs.open(fileName, 'a', 0755, function(err, fd) {
        if (err) throw err;
        fs.write(fd, buffer, null, 'Binary', function(err, written, buff) {
          fs.close(fd, function() {
            console.log('File saved successful!');
          });
        });
      });
    }
})
```

});

Thanks again.

Comment: Can you supply the lines of the log file that directly deal with the file upload causing your application to crash?  You can find out how to check the log files here: https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/log-files.html

Comment: Ok yep done it thanks

Comment: @HenryPeterBrianConfos What error?

Comment: As soon as i upload an image the server responds with error 503 then i have to restart it but the image does not save. Thanks